# Launching "emacs -nw" with 256color on a new xfce4-terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, emacs, xfce4

I have a litle question about launching emacs using this command

xfce4-terminal -e "emacs -nw"

I'm using **TERM=xterm-256color** in my .bashrc but it has effect only when i first launch a new xfce4-terminal before calling emacs -nw in two separate steps.

And of course, the reason I need this, is for launching emacs in a new terminal using hotkeys (lxde) with 256 color support. I tried many different solutions (.sh scripts, etc) but none has worked.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
xfce4-terminal -e "emacs -nw"
```

you are not running `bash` — rather, you are running `emacs` directly.  So your shell initialization is not used.

If you want to ensure that bash is run, you could do something like this

```
xfce4-terminal -e "bash -i -c 'emacs -nw'"
```

Comment: no problem (the odd quoting appeases both programs).